# Using react native ble plx to get data from smart kitchen scale. Managed to get value (It fluctuates when a weight is applied) but it is weird

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am using the react native ble plx module to connect to an escali smart kitchen scale, and am trying to get the value to show on my mobile application. I managed to get the value, but it is in a weird format. Upon using base64 to decode, I got back alt-code style values. How do I get the weight value (1,2,3,etc...) and unit (g/oz) from the value I got? I have tried comparing the output values from various weights and have managed to find some similarities and differences, however this does not help me in getting the value from it.

My Code:

```
manager.connectToDevice(item.id, { autoConnect: false }).then((item) => {

                          item.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics().then(() => {

                            item.services().then((service) => {

                              for (var x = 0; x < service.length; x++) {

                                item.characteristicsForService(service[x].uuid).then((result) => {

                                  for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
                                    
                                    if (result[x].isNotifiable === true) {

                                      item.monitorCharacteristicForService(result[x].serviceUUID, result[x].uuid, async (error: BleError | null, characteristic: Characteristic | null) => {
                                        
                                        // error handling
                                        if (error || !characteristic) {
                                          console.log(error);
                                          return
                                        }

                                        if (characteristic) {
                                          
                                          var raw = characteristic.value;
                                          var decodeVal = base64.decode(raw);
                                          console.log(`${raw}:  ${decodeVal}`);
                                          setWeight(decodeVal);
                                          
                                          if (raw.includes('AAAA', 4)) {
                                            setWeightUnit('g');
                                          } else {
                                            setWeightUnit('oz');
                                          }
                                        }
                                      })
                                    }
                                  }
                                })
                              }
                            })
                          })
                        })
```

My output:

```
 LOG  DAAAAAAAlwA=:

 LOG  DAAAAAAAFwA=:
↨
 LOG  DPAAAAAAFwA=:
ð↨
 LOG  DNUEAAAAFwA=:
Õ♦↨
 LOG  DNwGAAAAFwA=:
Ü♠↨
 LOG  DB8HAAAAFwA=:
▼↨
```

My services and characteristics: (i just pasted the main part)

```
"id": 2, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 1, "serviceUUID": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 3, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 1, "serviceUUID": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 4, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": true, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 1, "serviceUUID": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a02-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 5, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": true, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 1, "serviceUUID": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a03-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 6, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 1, "serviceUUID": "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a04-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 8, "isIndicatable": true, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": false, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 7, "serviceUUID": "00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 11, "isIndicatable": true, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": false, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 10, "serviceUUID": "0000780a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00008aa1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 14, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": true, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": false, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 10, "serviceUUID": "0000780a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00008aa2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 16, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 10, "serviceUUID": "0000780a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00008aa0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 18, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a23-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 19, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a24-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 20, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a25-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 21, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a26-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 22, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a27-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 23, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a28-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 24, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a29-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 25, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a2a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}

"id": 26, "isIndicatable": false, "isNotifiable": false, "isNotifying": false, "isReadable": true, "isWritableWithResponse": false, "isWritableWithoutResponse": false, "serviceID": 17, "serviceUUID": "0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "uuid": "00002a50-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb", "value": null}
```

Converted to hexadecimal:

```
(0 grams) => DAAAAAAAlwA= [0c 00 00 00 00 00 97 00]
(318 grams) => DD4BAAAAFwA= [0c 3e 01 00 00 00 17 00]
(156 grams) => DJwAAAAAFwA= [0c 9c 00 00 00 00 17 00]

(0 oz) => DQAA8AAAlwA= [0d 00 00 f0 00 00 97 00]
(11.2 oz) => DQBw8AAAFwA= [0d 00 70 f0 00 00 17 00]
(5.5 oz) => DQA38AAAFwA= [0d 00 37 f0 00 00 17 00]
```

Would appreciate any hints or help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you please add the UUIDs of the service and characteristic your scale offers?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply @MichaelKotzjan! I have updated the question to include the services and characteristics. I basically got the value from id:14 of the device as it is "isNotifiable", then all i did was "item.monitorCharacteristicForService()" to subscribe to that service and it will provide me with the values continuously till I unsubscribe. I applied a weight on the scale and indeed the output changed accordingly, therefore I am certain that is the value I wanted.

Comment: Ok so the service you are reading from is not a standard service, there probably is no documentation on it. You are getting weird characters because the output as text is wrong. Hexadecimal values would be more helpful. Please use this [online converter](https://cryptii.com/pipes/base64-to-binary) to convert the received values from base64 to hexadecimal values. Now we need to figure out whats what :) it would be great if you could get two readings with known weights, for example 1 and 2 kg.

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I have updated the the question to include the known readings as well as their data and converted hexadecimals.

Comment: UPDATE: @MichaelKotzjan I think I managed to get the values I want. Apparently hexadecimal is the way to go. Thank you so much for your help! Now I just need to find a way to do the conversion in the application itself and it should work fine. The only issue that I have now is that I have to swap the positions of the hexadecimal values for grams to get the correct value. Nonetheless, I really appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! I was actually typing an answer but you've been faster ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an unknown BLE protocol you need to find a pattern in the received values. Knowing the expected values is key.

Take a look at the values in grams:

```
(0 grams) =>   [0c 00 00 00 00 00 97 00]
(318 grams) => [0c 3e 01 00 00 00 17 00]
(156 grams) => [0c 9c 00 00 00 00 17 00]
```

The first value stays the same, the second and third change. For 0 grams it is actually `00 00` which was expected, let's take a look at 318g:

If we convert `3e 01` to decimal we receive a value of 15873, not what we expected. But sometimes devices store their values in different byte order, so let's try to reverse the order. Converting `01 3e` results in the expected value of 318.

The first byte is set to `0c` if grams are measured and `0d` if it's in oz. So that might be the flag to tell you what's actually measured.

The value for oz measurements also makes sense: the third byte contains the value (for these small amounts, might be different if larger values are sent). For example `70` in hex is 112 in decimal, just add a decimal point (by dividing by 10) and you get the expected value of 11.2.

That's just a starting point, you might be able to figure out the other values as well